# How should one define the sample variance for scalar input?

Tags: r, variance, matlab

I was horrified to find recently that Matlab returns $0$ for the *sample* variance of a scalar input:

```
>> var(randn(1),0)   %the '0' here tells var to give sample variance
ans =
     0
>> var(randn(1),1)   %the '1' here tells var to give population variance
ans =
     0
```

Somehow, the sample variance is not dividing by $0 = n-1$ in this case. R returns a NaN for a scalar:

```
> var(rnorm(1,1))
[1] NA
```

What do you think is a sensible way to define the <strike>population</strike> sample variance for a scalar? What consequences might there be for returning a zero instead of a NaN?

**edit**: from the help for Matlab's `var`:

```
VAR normalizes Y by N-1 if N>1, where N is the sample size.  This is
an unbiased estimator of the variance of the population from which X is
drawn, as long as X consists of independent, identically distributed
samples. For N=1, Y is normalized by N. 

Y = VAR(X,1) normalizes by N and produces the second moment of the
sample about its mean.  VAR(X,0) is the same as VAR(X).
```

a cryptic comment in the m code for `var states:

```
if w == 0 && n > 1
    % The unbiased estimator: divide by (n-1).  Can't do this
    % when n == 0 or 1.
    denom = n - 1;
else
    % The biased estimator: divide by n.
    denom = n; % n==0 => return NaNs, n==1 => return zeros
end
```

*i.e.* they explicitly choose not to return a `NaN` even when the user requests a sample variance on a scalar. My question is why they should choose to do this, not how.

**edit**: I see that I had erroneously asked about how one should define the population variance of a scalar (see strike through line above). This probably caused a lot of confusion.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about the population variance definition or about the *sample* variance definition?  There's no issue with the former.

Comment: @whuber I think what Matlab is doing is the following. When it encounters a scalar it reports the population variance by default. When it encounters a vector it reports the sample variance by default unless you ask it to report population variance. In either context they use same function: `var()`.

Comment: @Srikant That may be, but it does not address my request for clarification.  I suspect there may be a typographical error in the last line.  The var() function appears to be returning the correct values of population variance but not the correct values for *sample* variance.

Comment: @whuber Actually, `var(randn(1),0)` weights the variance by 0 and hence the output is 0. The second element is used to do a weighted average if it is different from 1. See: [Mathworks help for `var`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/var.html)

Comment: @srikant, the 'weight' is a red herring: mathWorks wanted to add weighted variance without boogering the API, so they added this odd option. At least, that is how I see it.

Comment: @Srikant Excellent!  What you have found is that the OP has mischaracterized the meaning of the second parameter.  *That* is a fine resolution of the question.  Why don't you point that out in your answer?  (Regardless, I think Matlab is using a terrible convention, even though they clearly document it.)

Comment: @shabbychef: The page Srikant has referenced clearly documents the behavior you have noted.  In particular, it does not maintain that var() returns the 1/(n-1) version of the variance when n=1.  So the issue is not that Matlab is *wrong*, per se.  (From a software design point of view this implementation of var() is terrible because it tries to do too much in a single function and consequently risks misunderstanding and erroneous results by unvigilant users.)

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is documented in the help for `var`, but the API for this function is annoying at best, as you point out. My question is _why_ do they do this? You simply cannot ask the Matlab `var` command to 'weight by zero'/give sample variance for  a scalar, it refuses to answer the question, pretending the user has asked a different question. What is the sensible answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scalars can't 'have' a population variance although they can be single samples from population that has a (population) variance.  If you want to estimate that then you need at least: more than one data point in the sample, another sample from the same distribution, or some prior information about the population variance by way of a model.

btw R has returned missing (NA) not NaN

```
is.nan(var(rnorm(1,1)))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: aha, I have not worked with R enough to spot the `NA` vs `NaN` distinction. Nice that it has both...

Comment: Of course a single number has a variance!  It's the mean square deviation from its mean, namely zero.  Perhaps you meant to say a dataset with one number cannot have a *sample* variance?

Comment: You'll notice that I said it can't have a *population variance*, not that it cannot have a variance.  Clearly it has a sample variance, which is indeed trivially zero.

Comment: I have come to realize that our conversation derives from two different understandings of "population" and "sample" variance. The terms are confused on the Internet, so I think we're both blameless and that we may be in agreement. I was attempting to use the convention adopted by the OP, whose terminology indicates the "sample" variance divides by n-1 while the "population" variance divides by n.  Incidentally, your comment seems (correctly) to allow for *three* variances: that of a random variable, the unbiased estimator thereof, and that of a set of independent realizations of it.

Comment: @whuber that sounds like an awesome discussion to have. I will try to think of a question for it :)

Answer (score 3):

I am sure people in this forum will have better answers, here is what I think:

I think R's answer is logical. The random variable has a population variance, but it turns out that with 1 sample you don't have enough degrees of freedom to estimate sample variance i-e- you are trying to extract information that is *NOT* there.

Regarding Matlab's answer, I don't know how to justify 0, except that it is from the numerator.

Consequences can be bizarre. But I can think of anything else related to the estimation.

Comment: Actually, a single observation of a random variable often provides information about that variable's variance.  It depends on the possibilities you allow.  For instance, a single observation from a Uniform, Poisson, or Exponential distribution lets you estimate its single parameter, which gives you an estimate of the variance.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the pointers. Actually, I was thinking more on the lines of sample variance. What I meant to say was, estimating sample variance may not be appropriate with one sample. It stands corrected now.

Comment: @whuber But this is not the case here; this function is documented to return variance/(n-1) and is returning 0 for 0/0 symbol.

Comment: @mbq You missed the disclaimer in the documentation: "For N=1, V is normalized by N."  That's an elliptical way of saying "For N=1, a value of 0 is returned."  The point I was making with my comment actually is about something else: it addresses @suncoolsu's assertion that "you are trying to extract information that is *NOT* there" in the case N=1.  On the contrary, a single observation from a random variable indeed *does* provide information about its variance in many practical applications.  (However, I am *not* saying that the variance is best estimated by some kind of variance formula!)

Comment: @whuber Fair enough; yet this does not justify this behavior.

Comment: @mbq I agree with you completely.  Sadly, even Mathematica has troubles with singleton datasets (in its "HypothesisTesting" package: it issues error messages but actually returns a confidence interval of [0,0] when asked for a CI for the variance of a single observation).  It seems that if you want to handle statistical estimators correctly you really need to use a true statistics package and not just some wannabe add-on to Matlab, Mathematica, Excel, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I think Matlab is using the following logic for a scalar (analogous to how we define population variance) to avoid having to deal with NA and NAN.

$Var(x) = \frac{(x - \bar{x})^2}{1} = 0$

The above follows as for a scalar: $\bar{x} = x$.

Their definition is probably a programming convention that may perhaps make some aspect of coding easier.

Comment: You have restated the problem without offering a resolution.  The concern is that this convention can lead to wrong answers when the variance estimate is used later.  It certainly delays the stage at which a failure is recognized.  (Think about what happens if you try to use this "variance" in a t-test, for instance.)

Comment: @whuber Not exactly. The OP is thinking that `var` returns the sample variance for a scalar whereas it returns the 'population variance'. Whether it is a problem or not depends on what type of error handling routines they have internally. However, I agree that their convention is susceptible to errors.

Comment: @Srikant In order to determine who is more confused, you or I, I have learned that we both are!  Wikipedia terms the formula with 1/(n-1) the "sample variance" (at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance ) whereas Mathworld clearly uses 1/n at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVariance.html .  However, the OP uses "sample variance" in the first sense when remarking that "the sample variance is not dividing by 0=n−1".  In this sense *there is no such thing* as "sample variance" for a dataset of one value (a "scalar"), so your characterization of what the OP is "thinking" looks incorrect.

Comment: +1 As I know MATLAB, I think your hypothesis is (sadly) true.